# How can I retrieve market ids for Solana token swap program?

Tags: solana, token-swap-program, solana-program-library, solana-web3js

Having mint addresses of two spl tokens on Solana mainnet, I need to find public key of all possible markets (i.e. `marketId` in the following code snippet) available on Solana to get token swap info from:

```
const tokenSwap = await TokenSwap.loadTokenSwap(
    con,
    new PublicKey(marketId),// << HERE
    TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
    payerAaccount
);
```

I could not find any repository (similar to Raydium or Serum lp addresses) on github or anywhere else. Where can I find a list of liquid markets for spl token swap program? and/or is there any other way to calculate or retrieve token swap info based on token mint addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the addresses of markets for two mint addresses, you'll need to go through a few steps.

- Get all of the program accounts for the token swap program: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts
- Deserialize each of those as a `TokenSwap` type by decoding, e.g. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/07bf49fdb820f8e3a40550998723e4878506af0b/token-swap/js/src/index.ts#L258
- Check that the `mintA` and `mintB` are the ones expected: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/07bf49fdb820f8e3a40550998723e4878506af0b/token-swap/js/src/index.ts#L65

Note, however, that the current `TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID` is deprecated by Serum in favor of using the Serum orderbooks.  You may have to use their SDKs for Serum, or Raydium's to interact with those programs.

Comment: Don't you know any API that does all these tasks and exposes an updated list of markets?

Comment: There's no API on the swap program, but if you're using Orca, they have an easy to use SDK: https://github.com/orca-so/typescript-sdk, Raydium also has an SDK: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk, and Serum has these resources: https://github.com/project-serum/serum-ts